# Using CDN when combining assets with Symfony2 and Assetic

Tags: symfony, assetic

I would like to use CDN together with Assetic in my Symfony2 project. I am using the `javascripts` helper to combine several Javascript files:

```
{% javascripts
  '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/file-1.js'
  '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/file-2.js' %}
  <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

and in my config.yml file I have registered a CDN to be used in the assets:

```
framework:
    templating:
      assets_base_urls:
        http: [http://my.cdn.url]
        ssl: [https://my.cdn.url]
```

When dumping, I do get a combined file, but its url is a relative one, not one pointing to the CDN. For instance:

```
<script src="/js/c713f83.js"></script>
```

And the same happens when combining several CSS files. The only way I managed to get URLs using the CDN is through `asset`:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/images/logo.png') }} ">
```

Is there anything preventing Assetic from using the CDN hosts I have specified in my configuration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to pass the Assetic's generated `asset_url` to the `asset()` Twig's function :

```
{% javascripts
  '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/file-1.js'
  '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/file-2.js' %}
  <script src="{{ asset(asset_url) }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Be aware that in `dev` environment you will get URLs that look like `http://my.cdn.url/app_dev.php/js/file-1.js`. In order to prevent that you have to configure your `dev` environment so it doesn't use CDN :

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
framework:
    templating:
        assets_base_urls:
            http: []
            ssl:  []
```

Remember dumping your assets with `assetic:dump` and, overall, remember that [Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) and the [Symfony2 `asset` Twig function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets) are two different things.

Comment: I'm having problems with the assets inside css files, for example, twitter bootstrap loads files for icons and using a cdn (Amazon S3) to store these files they are note loading.. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Easier solution than blanking out the assets_base_urls in config_dev.yml is to only place them in your config_prod.yml to start with, rather than the base config.yml.